# dropped frames over UDP

Tags: c++, qt, networking, udp, router

this is my first "question", I hope I do it right :)

I am experimenting with network programming and in particular I want to broadcast data from one machine to some other >10 devices using UDP, over a wireless network. The data comes in packets of about 300 bytes, and at about 30 frames per second, i.e., one every ~33ms. 
My implementation is based on the qt example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-broadcastreceiver.html

I am testing the application with just one client and experiencing quite a few dropped frames, not really sure why. All works fine if I used ethernet cables. I hope someone here can help me find a reason.

I can spot dropped frames because the packets contain a timestamp: After I receive one datagram, I can check for the difference between its timestamp and the last one received, if this is greater than e.g. 50ms, it means that I lost one packet on the way.
This happens quite often, even though I have a dedicated wi-fi network (not connected to the internet and with just 3 machines connected to a router I just bought). Most of the times I drop one or two packets, which would not be a problem, but sometimes the difference between the timestamps suggests that some >30 packets are lost, which is not good for what I am trying to achieve.

When I ping from one machine to the other, I get these values:

```
50 packets transmitted, 50 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.244/91.405/508.959/119.074 ms
```

pretty bad for a new router, in a dedicated network with just 3 clients, isn't it? The router is advertised as a very fast Wi-Fi router, with three times faster performance than 802.11n routers.

Compare it with the values I get from an older router, sitting in the same room, with some 10 machines connected to it, during office hour:

```
39 packets transmitted, 39 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.458/47.297/142.201/37.186 ms
```

Perhaps the router is defective?

One thing I cannot explain is that, if I ping while running my UDP client/server application, the statistics improve:

```
55 packets transmitted, 55 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.164/6.174/197.962/26.181 ms
```

I was wondering if anyone had tips on what to test, hints on how to achieve a "reliable" UDP connection between these machines over wi-fi. By reliable I mean that I would be ok dropping 2 consecutive packets, but not more.

Thanks.

**Edit**

It seems that the router (?) sends the packets in bursts. I am measuring the time it passes between receiving two datagrams on the client and this value is about 3 ms for a sequence of ~10 packets, and then, around 300 ms for the next packet. I think my issues at the client is more related to this inconsistency in the intervals between frames, rather than the dropped frames. I probably just need to have a queue and a delay of >300ms wrt to the server.

Comment: While UDP tends to have higher throughput than TCP, UDP is an unreliable protocol, it can and will drop packets, as well as you will be receiving packets out of order or duplicates of already received packets. You need to think about that when designing your application protocol, and be ready to handle those situations.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I do know that UDP is unreliable, and I do expect to drop a packet here and there. Unfortunately I am experiencing 30 packets being dropped in a row, which is too many to handle. I thought about writing more than one of my frames into each datagram, but I can't do that for so more than a few frames (the packets would get much larger than the MTU and I assume this would give problems).

Comment: Any comments on the ping timings of my new router? I am considering trying to bring it back to the shop and try another one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt, and nothing that belongs on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The first and easiest way to tackle any problem related to network is to capture them on wireshark. 
And also check if packets are really being sent out from broadcasting machine.

And also, based on your description if packets being transmitted fine with etherne cables and not with UDP then 
it could be issue with UDP port too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on trying a packet analyzer. I use port 33235 for UDP, which I believe should be OK.